# Trying to understand AIC and model explanatory power vs. model complexity

Tags: model-selection, aic, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am running a series of gam models using the mgcv package in R. They are attempting to model various intrinsic factors of an organism and it's growth rate. The two primary factors I am looking at are age and growth rate during the early life history (first 30 days).

I am running each factor as it's own model, and then running additive and interactive models which include both terms. "a" is the age only model, "g" is the early growth only model", "ag" is the age and growth additive model (no interaction terms), and "axg" is the interactive model.

I am then comparing models using corrected AIC, adjusted R^2 and estimated degrees of freedom.

My understanding is that AICc is supposed to be a way to compare models that looks at the explanatory power of the model with penalization for model complexity, or else over-parameterized models would be preferred every time. However, when I look at the comparison between AIC, R^2 and EDF (a measure of complexity), I get non-intuitive (to me) results: [image: a is the age only model, g is the early life growth model, ag is the additive (no interaction term) model with a and g, and axg is the interactive model]

The AIC values seem to suggest that the additive and interactive models (ag and axg) are slightly preferred relative to the age only model. They do have very slightly higher explanatory power (R^2), but seeminly at the cost of much higher complexity (edf). Based on the first 2 plots, I would have expected that the age only "a" model would have been the "best" model according to AIC. And while I realize that I shouldn't over-interpret from small differences in AIC, the fact that they are lower/better values at all confuses me.

So I assume I must not be understanding something about how AIC works or how one of the other factors I'm comparing with work.

Any help with thinking through/understanding this would be greatly appreciated.